# Add click events to newly added elements in pure JS

Tags: javascript

I want to add a click event to elements with class `item`. Work fine:

```js
const enlargables = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
enlargables.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert('hello');
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="item">test 1</div>
<div class="item">test 2</div>
```

But if the element is added dynamically after pageload, the event will *not* be added to the element.

How can I add the event to **newly** added elements with class `item` using pure JS? Similar to how document ready works in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your .item element is dynamically created. In other words, it is attached to the DOM later after your listeners are already assigned. Even delegation should be used to achieve this

**JavaScript:**

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   const hasClass = event.target.classList.contains('item');
   if(hasClass) {
    //Add your logic here
   }
});
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.item', (event) => {
   //Add your logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation on the nearest static ancestor.

```js
// document only used for demonstration
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // use .closest instead to handle clicks on the descendants of .item
  if (e.target.matches('.item')) console.log('click');
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const newItem = document.createElement('div');
  newItem.classList.add('item');
  newItem.textContent = 'test';
  this.before(newItem);
});
```

```html
<div class="item">test 1</div>
<div class="item">test 2</div>
<button>Add</button>
```